# Insert with Where Exists Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert a row into the Friend table if the username being entered already exists in table User. My code works if I remove the `WHERE EXISTS` statement but does not work with it.

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$friendname = $_POST["friendname"];
$friend = $friendname;

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO Friend (username, friend_username)
VALUES(?,?) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $friendname, $friend);   
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement); 
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Debug:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in
>   G:\PleskVhosts\playchesswithbrandon.net\httpdocs\UpdateFriendName.php
>   on line 3 PHP Notice:  Undefined index: friendname in
>   G:\PleskVhosts\playchesswithbrandon.net\httpdocs\UpdateFriendName.php
>   on line 4 PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1
>   to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in
>   G:\PleskVhosts\playchesswithbrandon.net\httpdocs\UpdateFriendName.php
>   on line 8 PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to
>   be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in
>   G:\PleskVhosts\playchesswithbrandon.net\httpdocs\UpdateFriendName.php
>   on line 9 PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given in
>   G:\PleskVhosts\playchesswithbrandon.net\httpdocs\UpdateFriendName.php
>   on line 10

Comment: There is nothing inside `$_POST`, or at least not a `username` and `friendname`. Print out all request vars (`print_r($_REQUEST)`), maybe you used get?

Answer (score 0):

before you use where exists you should select result which compare it with query inside the exists like this:

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO Friend (username, friend_username)

    SELECT username, friend_username
    FROM Friend 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ?)");
```

this [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/exists.php) may help you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your query should look something like this:

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO Friend (username, friend_username)
VALUES(?,?) WHERE COUNT(SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ?)=1");
```

You do this to make sure, that the user exists.

P.S. Using strings as PK is a really bad idea